# Using Jquery: Display error message one field at a time

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a reset password page, which has 2 fields. I added required validation rules for both fields. It works but the required error message for confirm password field will show up when i am still typing into the new password field. How to show error message for confirm password field only after I typed in?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#resetPassword").validate({

            rules : {
            newPassword: {
                  required: true},
            confirmPassword: {
                  required: true,
                  matchNewPassword: true},
            messages : {
                confirm_password : "<fmt:message key='reset.password.warning.confirm'/>"},

                }});

    $("#resetPassword input").on('keyup blur', function () { 
    if ($("#resetPassword").valid()) {                   
        $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);        
    } else {
        $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);  
    }
});
        });

         jQuery.validator.addMethod("matchNewPassword", function(value, element) {
            var password = $("#new_password").val();
            var confirm_password = $("#confirm_password").val();

            if(confirm_password != password ) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }, "<fmt:message key='reset.password.warning.confirm'/>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `'keyup blur'` use `'change'` event:

```
$("#resetPassword input").on('change', function () { ... };
```

Comment: Glad it helped. By the way, if you ever need to monitor input change, again do not use `keyup blur` etc, but `input` event. It would also trigger if you right click and paste some text inside, for example. You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dq5ddnvv/).

Comment: Got it! really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Edit your event listener with: `$("#resetPassword input").on('change', function () { //your code goes here };`

Comment: I have fixed it by the last answer. Thanks all the same!

Comment: @SophiaWu Upvote it then at least if you find it useful.

Comment: I voted for it but it seems not showing on the page.